# Extracting text preceding a particular string

Tags: shell-script, awk

I'm trying to grep a word per line. For each line, I'd like to print everything that appears before the grep'd word.

Example:

```
echo help.me.nc.example.com is an alias for fd-nc-001.domain.com.
```

I'm grepping for `.nc` and I would like to print out everything before it which would be `help.me`.

```
echo help.me.nc.example.com is an alias for fd-nc-001.domain.com. | awk '{print $6}'
fd-nc-001.domain.com.
```

```
echo help.me.nc.example.com is an alias for fd-nc-001.domain.com. | grep .nc | awk '{print $1}'
help.me.nc.example.com
```

Comment: If your input was `help.ncc1701.nc.example.com` what should the output be? If your input was `help.me.nc.foo.nc.com` what should the output be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This truncates the lines of input at the first occurrence of the string `.nc`:

```bash
sed 's/\.nc.*//'
```

(Note that the dot in `.nc` must be escaped as it would otherwise match any single character.  The `.*` after `\.nc` matches the rest of the line.)

This additionally does not output anything if the input line does not contain the string `.nc` (or rather, it only outputs something if the substitution is performed, which it would be if the line contains the string):

```bash
sed -n 's/\.nc.*//p'
```

The `-n` option to `sed` disables the default output of the buffer at the end of each cycle. Instead, the added `p` flag to the substitution command performs an explicit output whenever the substitution is triggered.

Example:

```bash
$ echo help.me.nc.example.com is an alias for fd-nc-001.domain.com. | sed 's/\.nc.*//'
help.me
```

```bash
$ echo help.me.XX.example.com is an alias for fd-nc-001.domain.com. | sed 's/\.nc.*//'
help.me.XX.example.com is an alias for fd-nc-001.domain.com.
```

```bash
$ echo help.me.nc.example.com is an alias for fd-nc-001.domain.com. | sed -n 's/\.nc.*//p'
help.me
```

```bash
$ echo help.me.XX.example.com is an alias for fd-nc-001.domain.com. | sed -n 's/\.nc.*//p'
```

(There is no output from that last command.)

---

Performing the equivalent operation as `sed -n 's/\.nc.*//p'` using only `awk`:

```bash
awk 'sub(/\.nc.*/, "")'
```

(Tries to perform the substitution on each line, but only prints the result if the pattern used in the `sub()` command matches.)

The same thing, but only using `pcre2grep`:

```bash
pcre2grep -o '.*?(*positive_lookahead:\.nc)'
```

(Matches the start of the line and everything up, but not including, the string `.nc`.)

You can use `(*pla:`, or the more cryptic `(?=`, in place of `(*positive_lookahead:` above.
If you have GNU `grep`, you can use `grep -P` in place of `pcre2grep` in the previous command.

Comment: Thank you so much!!  That did the trick!

 sed 's/\.nc.*//'

Comment: is there a way to combine a search?

`sed 's/\.nc.*//' | sed 's/\.nb.*//' | sed 's/\.nd.*//'`


I figured the following would work since I was able to do it for a different search/replace but didnt.

`sed 's/\.nc.*|\.nb.*|\.nd.*//'`


different example
`sed -E 's/nc-|nb-|nd-/n-/g'`

Comment: @dupa That specific example could be written `sed 's/\.n[bcd].*//'`. The second one would be `sed 's/n[bcd]\{0,1\}-//g'`

Comment: ok, there are so many different ways you can do this.  thanks for the much appreciated help!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you really want is to find `.nc` either followed by `.` or at the end of the line, and that you want to match on the first occurrence of that (as opposed to the last occurrence) on each line. That'd be either of these (using sample input that tests more than just the sunny day case of `.nc` appearing once in the input and not as a substring):

```
$ echo 'help.ncc1701.nc.foo.nc.com' | sed -E 's/\.nc(\..*|$)//'
help.ncc1701

$ echo 'help.ncc1701.nc.foo.nc.com' | awk 'sub(/\.nc(\..*|$)/,"")'
help.ncc1701
```

That sed command requires a sed that supports `-E` to enable EREs, e.g. GNU or BSD sed, while the awk command will work in any awk.